# Problem with static routing in Node.js using express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, single-page-application, url-routing

I am having an issue with some custom routing code, it all works fine and is in sync with the client-side view routing I do, but as soon as I have a subpage, it doesn't route my static files correctly.

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

Rather than giving me a file from the root directory, it'll serve it as if it were from the subfolder.

Example: i go to http://localhost/sign-up, and files loading in my index file from ***/scripts*** are loaded, but if i go to http://localhost/sign-up/2, it'll attempt to load the script from ***/sign-up/scripts***

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

app.use('/views', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend', 'views')));

app.use('/styles', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend', 'styles')));
app.use('/scripts', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend', 'scripts')));
app.use('/media', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend', 'media')));

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend', 'newSite.html'));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 1234, () => console.log('Server is now running...'));
```

To manage this I have been following these tutorials by DCODE on youtube, but I can't see anything amiss:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6BozpmSjk-Y

https://youtu.be/OstALBk-jTc

Comment: Probably a folder sturcture problem. You can see the same error in the video.

Comment: Could you elaborate? At what time stamp?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6BozpmSjk-Y 31:53

Comment: What `src` or `href` values are you using to load resources in the signup folder? They should be begin with a `/` to make them relative to the site root , e.g. `href="/styles/stylesheet.css"`, and not relative to the address of the html page - which they will be if the leading `/` is omitted.

Comment: @traktor that was the issue, I hadn't realised that I had made them relative to the current path by not using a "/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resources loaded in the sign up folder should use URLs beginning with a '`/`' character, to make them relative to the site root, e.g.

```
src="/scripts/modulefile.js"
href="/css/stylesheet.css"
href="/media/image.png"
```

and not urls relative to the signup folder - which they will be if the leading `'/'` is omitted.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need multiple routes to serve your static contents, and the `static` method of `express` do such kind of tasks for you:

```js
// If your 'public' or 'static' directory is one of root directories
app.use(express.static(process.cwd() + '/public'));

// so all these requests will be served:
// -> /public/styles/custom.css
// -> /public/scripts/pollyfils.js
// -> /public/media/logo.png
```

Comment: It doesn't explain nor solve the question and it certainly doesn't hurt the application.

Comment: @kmp If you had another and better solution please answer with your own solution. also if you have any suggestions then we could learn from

Comment: It might be a good idea at some point to put all my static directories into one, so thank you @Heartbit, but for the time being I will leave it as is as it gives me more controll over what I am serving and whats not accessible

Comment: your wlc, this is just a `separation of concern`  of your project file structure